# Is there any gain in removing old unused Handler Mappings in IIS 7?

Tags: performance, iis-7, handler-mappings

I want to clean up my live server after removing a Classic ASP subset from a live web application.

Other than cleaning up configuration, is there any other gains from disabling unused mappings in IIS? I guess performance may be a little faster, but if we are talking milliseconds gains for every 100,000 requests it's not worth it. Is there a way to measure the performance?